# Debug delayed load dll

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging

I'm using Eclipse and Cygwin-GCC to create a DLL file. This DLL is then executed by a third party application that I do not have the sources of. I just run it and sometimes it executes a function from my DLL.

Is it possible using Eclipse to attach the Cygwin-GDB to the third party process to debug just my own DLL file?
As far as I know Visual Studio can attach its debugger to a process. Would Visual Studio be able to do what I want out of the box?
And can this be achieved with Eclipse somehow too?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

To answer part of your question: yes, Visual Studio can do what you want out of the box... provided that you attach to the process before your code is executed. I'm not a huge Eclipse fan, so I don't use it and can't tell you if it has the capability to attach to an already-running process.

Regardless of what debugger you're using... since it's delayed loading, you can add something in your entry point like:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
#if ALERT_ATTACH_DEBUGGER
            ::MessageBox("Attach debugger now!", "Debug Alert", MB_OK);
#endif
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

When your message box appears, find the host process in the list and attach... after that, any breakpoints you set in your code will work.

Comment: Thx. I will try it this way but still hoping for an Eclipse way of doing it.